# How do I put a Server class on my website so my Client class can communicate with it from different computers?

Tags: java, web, networking, server, client

I have a server client application working just how I want it locally. I need to get the server online so the client program can be used from different computers. Not sure how to do this. I have my own website that I thought I could just put the Server on in the background.

Is this possible or am I just looking at this the wrong way.

## Server.java

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        int clientNum = 1; // keeps track of how many clients were created

        // 1. CREATE A NEW SERVERSOCKET
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // provide MYSERVICE at port
                                                    // 4444
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // 2. LOOP FOREVER - SERVER IS ALWAYS WAITING TO PROVIDE SERVICE!
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {

                // 2.1 WAIT FOR CLIENT TO TRY TO CONNECT TO SERVER
                System.out.println("Waiting for client " + clientNum + " to connect!");
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientNum++;
                ClientHandler c = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, clients);
                clients.add(c);
                // 2.2 SPAWN A THREAD TO HANDLE CLIENT REQUEST
                Thread t = new Thread(c);
                t.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            // 2.3 GO BACK TO WAITING FOR OTHER CLIENTS
            // (While the thread that was created handles the connected client's
            // request)

        } // end while loop

    } // end of main method

} // end of class MyServer

class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    Socket s; // this is socket on the server side that connects to the CLIENT
    ArrayList<ClientHandler> others;
    Scanner in;
    PrintWriter out;

    ClientHandler(Socket s, ArrayList<ClientHandler> others) throws IOException {
        this.s = s;
        this.others = others;
        in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run() {
        // 1. USE THE SOCKET TO READ WHAT THE CLIENT IS SENDING
        while (true) {
            String clientMessage = in.nextLine();
            // System.out.println(clientMessage);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try (PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("chat.txt"), true));) {
                        fileWriter.println(clientMessage);
                        fileWriter.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // System.out.println(others.size());
                    for (ClientHandler c : others) {
                        // System.out.println(c.toString());
                        c.sendMessage(clientMessage);
                    }

                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String str) {
        out.println(str);
        out.flush();
    }
} // end of class ClientHandler
```

## ClientSide.java

```
package core;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ClientSide extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private String name;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Thread serverListener;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    // /**
    // * Launch the application.
    // */
    // public static void main(String[] args) {
    // EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    // public void run() {
    // try {
    // ClientSide frame = new ClientSide();
    // frame.setVisible(true);
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
    // }
    // });
    // }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public ClientSide(String myName) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        serverListener = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String clientMessage = in.nextLine();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Receiving before dec: " + clientMessage);
                        clientMessage = Crypto.decrypt(clientMessage, "key");
                        System.out.println("Receiving after dec: " + clientMessage);
                        addLine(clientMessage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        serverListener.start();
        name = myName;
        setTitle("Client Side");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) topPanel.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        contentPane.add(topPanel);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setRows(7);
        topPanel.add(textArea);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(bottomPanel);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("Message");
        bottomPanel.add(lblMessage);

        textField = new JTextField();
        bottomPanel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // send string/message to server
                String clientMessage;
                try {
                    clientMessage = Crypto.encrypt(name + ": > " + textField.getText(), "key");
                    System.out.println("Sending: " + clientMessage);
                    out.println(clientMessage);
                    out.flush();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        bottomPanel.add(btnSend);
    }

    public void addLine(String text) {
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + text + "\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your website already has a server, it runs http. Your example code isn't in anyway compatible with http.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Server code runs on port 4444, so it doesn't in any way interfere with an HTTP web server running on the same machine.

Comment: I don't see any code in that client that communications with any server. But, since you server code uses port 4444, it should run fine on a server machine. If you can't connection to port 4444 on the server machine (you didn't show us how you try to do that), then it's likely that port 4444 is blocked by a software firewall on the server machine, or that port 4444 isn't routed through the firewall device that would usually be protecting a server.

Comment: I accidentally posted the wrong code for ClientSide.java. This is the correct code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your ClientSide class connects with your server applicztion on port 4444, you can do the following:

1. Package your client as jar file and run on each computer you want to distribute it to.
2. Ensure, each of those computers have JRE installed.
   3  Package your Server module as jar file
3. You should own your server or have admin right. So you can install Java if not there.
   Depending on OS, SSH skill might be required
4. Ensure PORT 4444 is enabled on your host server. firewall
5. Get the public IP address of your server and use it in your ClideSide code.